# Fetch the data from database and display into select drop down box using jquery in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I created the database and also fetched and display. But I want the fetching  data's are display into the dropdown(select)box, while using id or name

1) What are ways to do above job,
2) Its possible to include jQuery, Ajax 
3) My platform Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help you
N.B: You route must be GET and return json

Laravel php:

```
$options = Option::all()
return response()
        ->json($options)
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('path'); }}",
        type: "GET",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        success: function(data){ 
           $.each(data, function(key, value) {
           $('#mySelect')
           .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",key)
                .text(value)); 
           });
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You could use the version of jquery that you need

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you should just just create a route in laravel with method post. that respond json result, and in your jquery code you should use work with ajax function you retrieve the result and you put it in you dropdown box.

NOTE:  must be in your html head and 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') in ajax headers.

Comment: I don't know you send some code to my clarification

Answer (score 0):

## Laravel route

```
Route::post('test', function (Request $request) {
    $data = Your_MODE:all()
    Route::view('/test', 'test',['data' => $data]);
});
```

## Laravel blade

```
<select>
    @foreach ($data as $item)
        <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
    @endfor 
</select>
```

Comment: For jquery you should do it by yourself and I can correct you

Comment: its work but I need. If I fetching the data,  The data should be placed in a dropdown box,  If I select id,  The respective data's are show into the textbox for eg: The fields are Id, Name, Designation If I select Id in the dropdown box the Name, Designation field are show in different textbox ,Tell me what are ways

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'get-data',
        success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
             $('#select_id')
            .append($("")
            .attr("value",value.id)
             .text(value.name)); 
            })
         }
      })